# Java arithmetic operators ,Please explain the output

Tags: java

```
public class MainClass
{

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        int i = 13 - - 14 + + 15;
        // evaluate this as Right to Left associativity 
        // so (13 - (-14)) + + 15 = 27 + +15 = 42 --> correct 
        System.out.println(i);
     }
}
```

Since + and - has same precedence , so it will have right to left associativity.
So I thought that any expression like 13 - - 14 + + 15 will be considered as 13 - (-14 + + 15) and output will be 12, but output is coming 42.
Can anyone please explain the output?

Comment: Left-to-right associativity means that `A op B op C` is `(A op B) op C`, not `A op (B op C)`.

Comment: Thanks Oliver!! I have edited the question. + and - operator has right to left associativity.

Comment: The unary operators are right-to-left; the binary operators (i.e. addition and subtraction) are left-to-right.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at `13 - - 14 + + 15` like `13 - (-14)`, which is like `13 + 14`, which is `27`, followed by `+ (+ 15)`, which is like `+ 15`, which equals 42.

Answer (score 1):

If you evaluate the expression from left to right (as Java does), you start with `13 - - 14` which is the same as `13 - (-14)`, which is 27. `27+ +15` is 42.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluating from left to right it's 13 - (-14) + (+15) so 13 + 14 + 15 = 42